# How to train a neural network for contrastive loss

Tags: keras, neural-network

I have data of the form
y1, **x1**
y2, **x2**
...
I am trying to train a neural network function say `f` such that over a set of pairs xi, xj, f(**xi**) - f(**xj**) is trained to be similar to (yi - yj) i.e. pairwise loss

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconstruct the data, for each pair `Xi`, `Xj` the label will be `Yi-Yj`. since the problem is a regression problem use `MSE` as a loss function and that hopefully will lead to what you want.